# EF Core 7 + Oracle database = TPT inheritance doesn't work

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am not sure Oracle provider means something in this expression, because I have an impression that the issue is in EF Core. I was not able to find any reports of this problem, so may be I just missed something obvious.
I have 2 tables in Oracle, one "base" table with ID (which is generated by the database) and NAME and one "derived" table with ID (FK to the base table) and ANOTHERNAME. Corresponding entities look like this

```cs
[Table("BASE")]
public class Base
{
    [DataMember, Column("ID"), Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember, Column("NAME"), Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

[Table("DERIVED")]
public class Derived : Base
{
    [DataMember, Column("ANOTHERNAME"), Required]
    public string AnotherName { get; set; }
}
```

We have temporary Ids created at the client side for the entities, so EF model additionally configured to ignore it

```cs
public class BaseConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Base>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Base> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.Id).Metadata.SetBeforeSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
    }
}
```

After we add new instance of Derived entity to the context and try to save changes, we getting the following error from Oracle: "ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (???)".
The following SQL statement are actually generated and executed (I simplified them, leaving only meaningful part). EF correctly splits them into 2 separate batches. The first one

```sql
...
INSERT INTO "AAA"."BASE" ("NAME")
VALUES (:p3)
RETURNING "ID", INTO "lBASE_1"(1)."ID";
OPEN :cur0 FOR SELECT "lBASE"(1)."ID" FROM DUAL;
...
```

and the second one

```sql
INSERT INTO "AAA"."DERIVED" ("ANOTHERNAME")
VALUES (:p4)
RETURNING "ID" INTO "lDERIVED_0"(1)."ID";
OPEN :cur0 FOR SELECT "lDERIVED_0"(1)."ID" FROM DUAL;
```

As you may see the actual issue is with the second batch. EF doesn't insert ID from the base table to the SQL of the derived table, but instead it tries to return it as well, thinking it should be generated by the database.

After some debugging of EF Core code I can see the following in [ModificationCommand.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Relational/Update/ModificationCommand.cs)

```cs
...
void HandleColumn(IColumnMappingBase columnMapping)
{
    **var property = columnMapping.Property;**
    var column = columnMapping.Column;
    var storedProcedureParameter = columnMapping is IStoredProcedureParameterMapping parameterMapping
        ? parameterMapping.Parameter
        : null;
    var isKey = property.IsPrimaryKey();
    var isCondition = !adding
        && (isKey
            || storedProcedureParameter is { ForOriginalValue: true }
            || (property.IsConcurrencyToken && storedProcedureParameter is null));

    // Store-generated properties generally need to be read back (unless we're deleting).
    // One exception is if the property is mapped to a non-output parameter.
    var readValue = state != EntityState.Deleted
        && **ColumnModification.IsStoreGenerated(entry, property)**
        && (storedProcedureParameter is null || storedProcedureParameter.Direction.HasFlag(ParameterDirection.Output));
...
```

This method initialize command parameter and is called for all column mappings in the command. And column mappings for derived class in additional to the explicit column "ANOTHERNAME" contain implicit column "ID" which is the key from the base class (this is correct). But when it takes "property" from this mapping, it actually takes property of the base class with all related configurations (doesn't matter by attributes or in code). And obviously "readValue" will be true because ColumnModification.IsStoreGenerated returns true for the base ID property. And when readValue is true, it doesn't go to the command parameters list and instead "RETURNING" statement is generated for it.

AFAIR TPT inheritance in our project worked in EF Core 6 and stopped working in EF Core 7. But so far we didn't investigate this and instead refactored our code to avoid TPT. But now we at the point when we cannot do this and have to use TPT. So I am not sure if we just missed some additional configuration that need to be done in EF Core 7 for TPT or is this really a bug. Any help will be appreciated.